# Expect statement prompt

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

I am trying to match a prompt but the OR statement inside parenthese `(%|#)` is not working.

The following is WORKING only for % ending prompts and NOT WORKING with # ending prompts :

```
set FULLPROMPT "${HOST} (.+)(%|#) $"
```

The following is NOT WORKING at all for any prompt :/ :

```
set FULLPROMPT "${HOST} (.+)% $"
```

I am missing something obviously.

The prompts can be like this

```
12:33 user@hostname ~%
12:33 root@hostname /usr/local/folder#
```

Expect is running as

```
set HOST "hostname"
set FULLPROMPT "${HOST} (.+)(%|#) $"
send "\n"
expect -re $FULLPROMPT
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: your regex has space `(.+)(%|#) $` after `%` or `#`? you checked that?

Comment: yes it as a space in both cases after the % and #

Comment: i suspect that your input string may not have space after `%` or `#`?

Comment: What do you mean input string ? The prompts looks like this : `13:02 user@hostname~% cmd`
`13:02 root@hostname /home/user# cmd`

Comment: Are there any colored or bold characters in the prompt? That might put an ansi escape sequence after the # instead of a space. Run the script with `expect -d` to see what is really going on.

Comment: @Franck i mean the prompts. now i got you saying.

Comment: @SchelteBron yes there are colors ! Hmm... !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Schelte Bron, I now can see exactly how the regex matches the prompts.
It turns out that the prompt has colors and this put all sort of characters before and after the `%` or `#`.

To overcome this you can either

1. overide the prompt PS1 variable
2. take care of all the hidden characters of the prompt in the regex
3. capture the prompt when logging in and use it in the regex (seems like what we SHOULD do but this seems a lot of work)

Run expect in debug mode :

```
expect -d
```

Comment: Overriding the prompt is one of the easiest solutions, FWIW.